# Naive use of java enums' ordinal in the context of JPA spelling disaster in the domain model

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, enums, ordinals

I would like to describe a nasty issue that occurs when making **naive use of Java enums in the context of JPA entities**. Let's take a look at how this problem can occur.

First the **domain model**:

Say I have an `Text` JPA entity that **represents piece of text (novel, news article, etc.)**. Here is the JPA entity:

```
@Entity
public class Text {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Long id;

    @Version
    @Column(name = "version")
    private Integer version;

    private String content;

    @Enumerated
    @ElementCollection
    private Set<Style> styles;

    //Setters and getters omitted.
```

To an instance of `Text`, **one or many styles can be applied such as italic, bold and so on**. The style is represented as a java enum.

To start with, we assume that **the application starts its life with the following enum**:

```
public enum Style {
  BOLD, ITALIC
}
```

The test below will then insert the following lines in a relational database:

*Integration test:*

```
@Test
@Rollback(value=false)
public void inEarlyLifePersist() {
    Text text =new  Text();
    text.setContent("This is my beautiful novel...");
    text.setStyles(EnumSet.of(Style.BOLD, Style.ITALIC));
    text.persist();
}
```

*Data in text table:*

```
# id, content, version
11, This is my beautiful novel..., 0
```

*Data in text_style table:*

```
# text, styles
11, 0
11, 1
```

Then, later on, some ill-advised developer decides **to add a new style**: `STRIKE_THROUGH` to our `Style` enum placing this new enum constant/value as the first one:

```
public enum Style {
    STRIKE_THROUGH, BOLD, ITALIC
}
```

and then a `new record is inserted in DB as follows`:

```
    @Test
    @Rollback(value=false)
    public void afterChangeToEnumPersist() {
        Text text =new  Text();
        text.setContent("This is my beautiful short story...");
        text.setStyles(EnumSet.of(Style.STRIKE_THROUGH, Style.BOLD));
        text.persist();
    }
```

*In text table:*

```
# id, content, version
14, This is my beautiful short story..., 0
```

And *in text_style table:*

```
# text, styles
14, 0
14, 1
```

**Obviously, the domain model is seriously compromised now!**

***My question is what are the possible strategies to avoid spelling disaster in the domain as is the case above*** (other than the obvious solution to place the `STRIKE_THROUGH` enum constant **after** `ITALIC`)?

**edit 1**: Obviously I do not want to store strings (see `EnumType.STRING`) in my database for obvious performance reasons i.e. data retrieval and storage performance would be seriously affected!

Comment: If you can't trust your developer, there is nothing stopping them from messing up your mapping that 'handles' the situation either.  Comments are the only way I can think of to let future code maintainers know order is there for a reason, that and QA tests.

Comment: I have to disagree with that line of thinking Chris. Comments should be reserved for things that are out of your control and are not surprising. The order of declaration of your enums should not be reliable piece of information. Sure you could comment this (and every other enum) but that is a poor solution that just adds to the massive number of pieces of trivia a developer must juggle. We're trying to reduce the number of things to juggle so they can spend their mental cycles being productive instead.

Comment: @corsiKa: I rather disagree. If you find the enum declaration order unreliable, then you surely find also their names and even the auxiliary numbers in the answer below unreliable. But then you've already excluded all solutions, game over. I agree that a comment doesn't suffice, see my answer.

Comment: @maaartinus In -most- situations (as in every situation that would actually happen, not a contrived one) changing the order of the declaration would not break java code, but would break relational code relying on it. Changing the names of something would necessitate a Java code change as well, making it much more reliable that the database code change would occur as well. Changing the auxiliary number would face the same fate as declaration order, although those auxiliary numbers are probably defined by a spec which gives a smidgen of reliability for that.

Comment: Concerning the name change, I meant just renaming an enum, which is pretty trivial (imagine someone fixing a type like [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_referer) or finding a better name) as the IDE does all the work. Rather than a problem with database *code* I see a problem with database *data*, which might be too hard to fix (imagine a terrabyte DB for a 24/7 service). Depending on ordinals makes it trivial.

Answer (score 3):

You need to redefine your `enum` like below.

```
public enum Style {
    STRIKE_THROUGH(2), BOLD(0), ITALIC(1)

    Style(int code){
      this.code=code;
    }
}
```

And implement a [Hibernate User type](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.6/reference/en-US/html/types.html#types-custom) to persist the `code`.

Comment: This could help, but why do you believe that developers changing the order don't change the `code`?

Answer (score 1):

There's an option (EnumType.STRING) to use the actual name of the enum value (the String returned by { name() } instead of the ordinal. That way you can reorganize your enum values, but then you are tied to the names of the enum values.

The ideal solution would be to be able to declaratively tell the JPA implementation to use an arbitrary property of the enum as the database identifier. But AFAIK, that it's not provided in the current JPA specs, it would be great to have such a feature in future JPA specs.

The answer by Sajan shows how to implement that using a Hibernate-specific feature.

Comment: Same comment about EnumType.STRING: This would kill database performance: i.e. data retrieval and storage!

Comment: Yes, none of the solutions provided by the current specs is ideal.

Answer (score 1):

The [Enumerated](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/Enumerated.html) annotation also knows a property that specifies the [EnumType](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/EnumType.html). Two types exist: `EnumType.ORDINAL` and `EnumType.STRING`. ORDINAL is the default one.

So, if you do it the following way

```
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
```

you will see the enumeration names in the DB column (and not the ordinals). Of course, you are now vulnerable to name changes in your enumeration. You have to die one death, but I think, the names are better.

Comment: This would kill database performance: i.e. data retrieval and storage!

Answer (score 1):

I can't see why people find the enum names more reliable than their ordinals. Actually, there are many good reasons for renaming enums (fixing typos, changed names due to politics or political correctness, etc.), but I can't see any good reason for reordering them.

Both renaming and reordering happens and the only thing which can help is a test. Unfortunately, the best test I can think of will fail on any change. Fortunately, the test can tell what happened and then be fixed easily.

```
public void testE1IsStable() {
    assertEnumUnchanged(E1.class, 4, "bec419c8380dbe9ec3b86a7023a55107");
}

public void testE2IsStable() {
    assertEnumUnchanged(E2.class, 3, "1e89e93c6cbdbb7311b814c19d682548");
}

private void assertEnumUnchanged(Class<? extends Enum<?>> enumClass, int expectedCount, String expectedHash) {
    final Object[] enumConstants = enumClass.getEnumConstants();
    if (expectedCount < enumConstants.length) {
        final Object[] shortened = Arrays.copyOf(enumConstants, expectedCount);
        assertEquals("Enum constants may be only appended! Ask balteo!",
            expectedHash, hashAsString(shortened));
        fail("An enum constant has been added! This test needs to be updated. Ask balteo!");
    } else if (expectedCount > enumConstants.length) {
        fail("Enum constants must not be removed! Ask balteo!");
    } else {
        assertEquals("Enum constants must not be reordered! If they get renamed, this test must be updated. Ask balteo!",
            expectedHash, hashAsString(enumConstants));
    }
}

private String hashAsString(Object[] enumConstants) {
    final Hasher hasher = Hashing.md5().newHasher();
    for (final Object o : enumConstants) hasher.putUnencodedChars(o.toString());
    return hasher.hash().toString();
}
```