# Improving JPA entity classes for existing DB schema

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, enums

I am attempting to implement a Hibernate/JPA2 solution over an existing schema, which cannot be changed.   Here is a minimal example of the existing schema:

```
CREATE TABLE REASON (
  REASON_CODE CHAR(1),
  REASON_DESCRIPTION CHAR(50))

CREATE TABLE HEADER (  
  REASON_CODE CHAR(1),
  OTHERFIELD1 CHAR(40),
  OTHERFIELD2 CHAR(40) )
```

Normally this would be the "correct" way from a DB perspective:  Link REASON to HEADER by the REASON_CODE.   However it's presenting me with an awkward problem in Java and I'm not sure of the best way to solve it.  I've modeled these entities as follows:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="REASON")
public class Reason  implements java.io.Serializable {
    @Id
    @Column(name="REASON_CODE", unique=true, nullable=false, length=1)
    private Character reasonCode;
    @Column(name="REASON_DESCRIPTION", nullable=false, length=25)
    private String reasonDescription;
}


@Entity
@Table(name="HEADER")
public class Header implements java.io.Serializable {
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "REASON_CODE", nullable = false)
    private Reason reason;
    @Column(name="OTHERFIELD1")
    private String otherField1;
    @Column(name="OTHERFIELD2")
    private String otherField2;
}
```

Once again, as far as I can tell, this is "correct" from a Java perspective - linking Header to Reason with a reference.

The problem is that when I need to use one of these Reason values in my code I wind up with awkward syntax like:

```
Reason r = reasonService.findOne('X'); //  X is the REASON_CODE in the database record
// Do some processing with variable r
```

Or this:

```
header.setReason(reasonService.findOne('X'));
```

Ideally I could implement Reason as an enum like:

```
public enum Reason {
    X_MARKSTHESPOT("X"),
    C_MEANSSOMETHINGELSE("C"),
    F_MEANSATHIRDTHING("F") ;

    private String code;

    private Reason(String code) {
        this.code = code;
    }
}
```

And then simply have this in my code:

```
header.setReason(Reason.X_MARKSTHESPOT);
```

But from what I [understand](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2751733/map-enum-in-jpa-with-fixed-values/2751896#2751896) that is not possible with JPA, which offers only EnumType.STRING (basically the name) or EnumType.ORDINAL (even worse, the index in the enum list).  A possible way around this would be JPA 2.1's [Converter](http://java.dzone.com/articles/mapping-enums-done-right), but I have never used it.   I have also read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19003307/naive-use-of-java-enums-ordinal-in-the-context-of-jpa-spelling-disaster-in-the?rq=1) (in one of the answers) that a [Hibernate User Type](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.6/reference/en-US/html/types.html#types-custom) might be useful.  One of our programmers has solved this in another app by writing two complete classes - an enum class for internal use and a "shadow" class which iterates through the enum and syncs the records in the database on every startup.   But this seems like a kludgey way to do it.   **What is the best way to handle this, bearing in mind that the database schema cannot be changed?**

Comment: If you don't want to implement a Converter: What is wrong with your initial approach? You could use good old char-constants instead of enums!

Comment: If the list of reasons is fixed and immutable (as it seems to be, since you would like to use an enum to represent it), you don't need to map the Reason table as an entity. Directly store the reasonCode in Header as a Character, String or enum.

Comment: What if reason table was defined as reason description table, which refers to entities in another data source (Java enum)?

Comment: I like JBNizet's answer, but I think I'm going to go with @isnot2bad's simpler solution in the short term - there is a mountain of existing code and refactoring it right now would be near-impossible for schedule reasons.